# Fixed footer kick outside html layout during Chrome Inspect

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed

I am trying to make a simple footer that is always at the bottom of the page. The content of the page will never exceed the screen size so no need to scroll down. (Basically there will be 5 different html pages and I want the footer and header to always be the same.)

However, once I make the footer "fixed", when I inspect the page in Chrome, the footer is no longer a part of the body or html layout.

I can get the footer to appear on the screen as I need to(using a wrap to set the width to 65% and centered) but I think the footer is supposed to be highlighted upon inspection when pointing on body and html.

Any idea why this is occurring? It seems to occur based upon the footer's position being changed to fixed.

Here is the HTML and relevant CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" 
  integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Play2Learn Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <h1>Play2Learn Logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="border" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                <li id="games-li"><a class="border" href="#">Games</a> 
                    <ul id="games-ul">
                        <li><a href="games/anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt </a></li>
                        <li><a href="games/math-facts.html">Math Facts Practice</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="border" href="about.html">About</a></li> 
                <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
    <div id="testimonial">Happy Clients Say...</div>
    <div id="quote">"I never have more fun than when I'm playing Anagram Hunt. It's the best game I've ever played!"</div>
    <div id="author">-Justin Jest</div>
    <section id="grids">
        <div id="grid1">
            <h3 class="article-title">Anagram Hunt</h3>
                <article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor 
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus.
                    Praesent vel rutrum lectus.
                    Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, 
                    ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. 
                    Sed eu luctus sem.
                </article>
            <a href="games/anagram-hunt.html" title="Play Anagram Hunt"><button>Play</button></a>
        </div>
        <div id="grid2">
            <h3 class="article-title">Math Facts Practice</h3>
                <article id="article2">Lorem ipsum dolor 
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus.
                    Praesent vel rutrum lectus.
                    Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, 
                    ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. 
                    Sed eu luctus sem.
                </article>
            <a href="games/math-facts.html" title="Play Math Facts Practice"><button>Play</button></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
    <footer>
    &#169 2021 Play2Learn
    <a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>

footer {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    }
    
 footer a {
     color: inherit;
     font-size: 46px;
     padding-left: 1rem;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer

Here it is integrated with your code:

```css
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%
}

#container {
  margin-left:0.5em;
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

header {
  padding:0.1px;
}
  
main {
  padding-bottom:60px;  /* Height of the footer */
}
  
footer {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}

 footer a {
   color: inherit;
   font-size: 46px;
   padding-left: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" 
  integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Play2Learn Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Play2Learn Logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="border" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                <li id="games-li"><a class="border" href="#">Games</a> 
                    <ul id="games-ul">
                        <li><a href="games/anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt </a></li>
                        <li><a href="games/math-facts.html">Math Facts Practice</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="border" href="about.html">About</a></li> 
                <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
    <div id="testimonial">Happy Clients Say...</div>
    <div id="quote">"I never have more fun than when I'm playing Anagram Hunt. It's the best game I've ever played!"</div>
    <div id="author">-Justin Jest</div>
    <section id="grids">
        <div id="grid1">
            <h3 class="article-title">Anagram Hunt</h3>
                <article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor 
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus.
                    Praesent vel rutrum lectus.
                    Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, 
                    ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. 
                    Sed eu luctus sem.
                </article>
            <a href="games/anagram-hunt.html" title="Play Anagram Hunt"><button>Play</button></a>
        </div>
        <div id="grid2">
            <h3 class="article-title">Math Facts Practice</h3>
                <article id="article2">Lorem ipsum dolor 
                    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus.
                    Praesent vel rutrum lectus.
                    Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, 
                    ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. 
                    Sed eu luctus sem.
                </article>
            <a href="games/math-facts.html" title="Play Math Facts Practice"><button>Play</button></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
    <footer>
    &#169 2021 Play2Learn
    <a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Notice that the footer height is set in the `padding-bottom` for main.)

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was not having "height: 100%" on the html and body elements. Once I added that I could do whatever I wanted with the footer (absolute, fixed, etc.) and use wraps and all the rest.   Cannot thank you enough!